# Upgrade/Migrate from Multiple Activity Intents to Single ViewPager & Fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager

I used to have 3 activities with 3 layouts.

```
1. HomeActivity.java (activity_home.xml)
2. HelpActivity.java (activity_help.xml)
3. SettingsActivity.java (activity_settings.xml)
```

Whenever i had to open other activities, i used animated slide-in-out intents using `overridePendingIntent`. In this way, all the variables of HomeActivity stayed in itself and HelpActivity's variables/methods were in itself and same for SettingsActivity. I used `onCreate()` in these to perform some *activity specific code*. and, `android:onClick="fetchSarcasm"` from `activity_home.xml` was calling specified method in `HomeActivity.java`. So, there were no conflicts. All the normal things, that happen in an AndroidProject with 3 activities and used intents to switch to one another, were happening as i wanted.

But now, I wanted to migrate to ViewPager instead of slide-in-out intent transitions. In this way, there will be only one Activity with an XML of ViewPager. This ViewPager and its FragmentPagerAdapter gets the Pages from 3 classes extending `Fragment` with relative XML layouts.

I want to ask: Where do i write my *Page Specific Code* for `onCreate()`, `layoutView's onClick=""` and for `onChangeListeners`. Because, 3 classes extending `Fragment` do not have any `Context` or `findViewById()` and they do not respond to `android:onClick="method"` in different layouts.

Do i need to mix all that code of three activities into one containing ViewPager? If so, this makes ViewPager activity pretty heavy. and, writing `if(page=2){ dothis(); }` seems absurd for all pages at every code point. Any checkbox(view) that is in page 3, becomes null in other pages.

I know this might be a stupid question. I have spent almost 4 days trying to achieve something but i can't. Also, this is just my 2nd month in android, so i am new. I do not use Action Bars, Tabbed Bars or Navigation Drawers.

I am available on SO Chat too if you want to ask something more.

I just want to know how do i merge all the work i did when I was not using ViewPager.

Comment: `Fragment`s in `ViewPager`s aren't necessarily recreated when you swipe to them. Does your `onCreate()` code really have to be called every time the Fragment becomes visible to the User?

Comment: No, `onCreate()` is not required on every page change. In `onCreate()`, I restore some of the sharedPreference which leads to decide if CheckBoxes are checked or not. I think this can be done through `setOnPageChangeListener` but everytime?

Comment: You can read your Preferences in `onViewCreated()` or alternatively in `onCreateView()` of each `Fragment`, then set your Checkboxes accordingly.

Comment: Check this http://www.journaldev.com/10096/android-viewpager-example-tutorial  and http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-viewpager-gallery-images-and-texts-tutorial/

Comment: @FloWe you can add your answer. I used `onViewCreated()` and I, also, found that Fragment shouldn't even know about whether an Activity or ViewPager is using it. So, all the UI Interaction related code stays in Fragments.

Comment: @rupinderjeet47 glad you got it working. ViewPagers are sweet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only reading the Preferences once for each `Fragment`, you can move your previous `Activity.onCreate()` logic to each `Fragment`s `onViewCreated()` or `onCreateView()`. Read your shared Preferences there and set your Checkboxes accordingly.

`Fragment`s inside a `ViewPager` aren't necessarily recreated on each page change. You can change how many `Fragment`s are instantiated at a time with `ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(int)`.

[Fragment Lifecycles explained](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating)